# ASP.Net Identity 2.0 Unattended Login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I'm using ASP.Net Identity 2.2 in a web application and it's working great.

What I want to do is have a background service that accesses the web application in order to generate Thumbnails and / or pdfs of some of the pages. This service may end up running as within the w3wp.exe process and is triggered by certain web requests made by users, e.g. the user changes some settings and the background service is triggered to regenerate the thumbnails.

The problem is allowing the background service to access the pages without opening a back-door that others could use to access the pages. Currently I have code that can copy the authentication cookies from a web request and use them to request the pages and generate thumbnails but I need to be able to do this WITHOUT any existing connection to copy the cookies from. It needs to be able to get its own cookies.

The libraries I am using to generate PDFs / Thumbnails work by making normal web requests to the web server and use headless browsers. I need to go through the web server as the pages include a lot of javascript and ajax so static pages would be difficult to generate.

Ideally it should use a "system" user that nobody on the web can log in as.

I don't want to be storing the password for a user in a form that can be revseribly decoded (all passwords are hashed in the database).

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

I had the idea that if there were a solid way to identify a request was coming from the thumbnail service then the server could just call the signin() function without needing a password but that is of course a difficult problem in itself as we would want to protect against people running web browsers on the server to bypass security. I wasn thinking maybe a shared (single use) secret but not sure if this can be done securely enough.

Comment: You can create another user for background service and set role for it like BackgroundServiceApp role. Than you write api where only this role can access and in that api later your service uses this userAccount to login & access its own app api where it can get users info. If you're using Azure you can check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798668.aspx also you can use Azure Queue or Amazon Simple Queue.

Comment: A separate API is not a route we want to take as we are trying to generate thumbnails / PDFs that look the same as what the user sees on their screen so it makes sense for the service to access the same pages as the users and thus reduce duplication of effort, i.e. just put an extra step on the end of the pipeline instead of having two different pipelines accessing the same data.

Comment: @Mog0 a common approach these days is to build an API first, and then have both your UI and any other automated services use the same API to access the data. That way you'd avoid the duplication problem you've just described. Obviously doesn't help so much if you've already built your UI, but just thought I'd mention it for the future.

Comment: @ADyson I do agree but we're adding a new interface onto a product that's over 10 years old so lots of legacy stuff. Plus we're trying to replicate the presentation as well as the data so in this case it makes sense to use a headless browser to take snapshots, it's just how to do that securely when you don't have an actual user involved.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the service run with a particular user of your web service and then allow that user to access the specified resources of your web site, adding to your `web.config` something like this:

```
<location path="yourdomain/yourresource">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="domainname\user" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

In this way you will not have to create a fake user that has zero business value, nor hardcode or configure username and password in your service.

Comment: Interesting idea but many of our customers need to have windows integrated authentication disabled in their IIS settings so I don't think that would work in those cases, i.e. the web application would not know the windows user the request has come from.

Comment: Therefore I think you should consider configuring or hard coding user and password in your service because in a way or the other your service will have to authenticate against your web app

Comment: @Mog0 another idea could be [this one](http://serverfault.com/questions/392606/iis-windows-authentication-except-for-local-machine); you could have a website that require authentication and another that doesn't require it (with IP restriction) that will be accessed only by your service. But I would not go that way honestly.

Comment: I wouldn't want to go the way of IP restriction as someone who could run a web browser on the server could get access to the data without being authenticated. The extra configuration is undesirable as our application is deployed on lots of different customer sites and we don't want to increase the support load any further, supporting customers installing / configuring the product.

Comment: @Mog0 I agree with you, let me know for sake of curiosity the choice you will make once you decide